# Jump if not equal is still jumping even when equal

Tags: winapi, assembly

```
include 'win32ax.inc'
.code
start:
mov bx, 60
mov ax, 60
cmp ax, bx
jne inv
inv:
invoke MessageBoxA, NULL, "Hello!", "Notice:", NULL, MB_OK
invoke ExitProcess, 0
.end start
```

BX & AX both have 60, so why's it jumping to the label & calling the message box? It's doing that.

Working solution by Jose:

```
include 'win32ax.inc'
.code
start:
mov bx, 60
mov ax, 60
cmp ax, bx
jne inv
jmp THEY_ARE_EQUAL
inv:
invoke MessageBoxA, NULL, "Hello!", "Notice:", NULL, MB_OK
invoke ExitProcess, 0

THEY_ARE_EQUAL:
invoke ExitProcess, 0
.end start
```

Comment: "Jumping, it does not, sliding do it does." our dear old friend Yoda would say. Move your label down and use a ``je inv`` to fix it :)

Comment: No, it actually jumps by changing the program counter, doesn't it? And JE would make it call the function; I want it to purposefully NOT call it because it's tested that they are both not NOT equal.

Comment: Does it have a choice? What is it supposed to do after ``jne inv`` if they are equal? Freeze up for eternity? So, of course the PC moves to the next instruction which just happens to be the invoke.

Comment: They are equal. What are you talking about? It's NOT jumping because NOT equal.

Comment: 60/60. IF NOT SAME -> GO HERE. They are the same, so "if not" means yes, go there. It's a little trick of inverse AND logic and it takes some people time to really understand. It's not for convenience; just because.

Comment: A conditional jump only jumps if the test is a success. Else it MOVES TO THE NEXT INSTRUCTION. If you place your label at the next instruction, you end there NO MATTER WHAT. Omg...

Comment: Something tells me I have a different sense of logic than you do. I believe in inverse logic clauses.

Comment: @Margaret Why do you ask questions if you think you know better than everyone else. When a large number of people tell you the same message, perhaps you should try harder to understand. You've not got to the bottom of this yet, but your mind is closed to learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a label in case AX BX are not equal. Add another label in case THEY ARE EQUAL:

```
mov bx, 60
mov ax, 60
cmp ax, bx
jne inv              ;JUMPS TO INV IF AX BX AREN'T EQUAL.
jmp THEY_ARE_EQUAL   ;JUMPS TO THEY_ARE_EQUAL IF AX BX ARE AEQUAL.
inv:
...
JMP continue       ;SKIP "THEY_ARE_EQUAL".
THEY_ARE_EQUAL:  
...
continue:
```

Comment: What is jmp continue? It just gives me a compilation error.

Comment: Tell me, what error? Remember to add your code in case they are not equal and another code in case they are equal (the "invoke" you have).

Comment: Thanks anyways ... your answer was the only solution that helped! The error is irrelevant; the point is that you need an IN CASE option or else it executes the next instruction regardless.

Comment: Exactly : IF . . . THEN . . . ELSE.

Comment: I mean, this is the implementation of an IF in assembler.

Comment: Very simple. :) You need some more tutorials.

Answer (score 6):

He's telling you to use a simpler approach. Move your label past the MessageBoxA invocation, and change the branch type to its inverse, je:

```
include 'win32ax.inc'
.code
start:
mov bx, 60
mov ax, 60
cmp ax, bx
je skip
invoke MessageBoxA, NULL, "Hello!", "Notice:", NULL, MB_OK
skip:
invoke ExitProcess, 0
.end start
```

And since you're calling ExitProcess with a code of 0 either way, you can leave out the redundant call and let the invocation of MessageBoxA fall through your skip label straight to the ExitProcess call.

Comment: Plus 1. Your solution is the only sensible one for the given problem but apparantely Margaret Rosa likes the overcomplicated solution by Jose better.

Answer (score 3):

Your label immediately follows your `jne` instruction, so even if the jump doesn't take place, the next instruction that gets executed is the same. Move the label one line down and try again; then you'll see the difference.

Comment: What do you mean "solution"? It depends on what you actually want to do. You didn't specify what the expected behaviour is....

Comment: Clearly I DON'T want it to call the message box function and that should be crystal clear.

Comment: Also, I moved the label one line down and it still called the function.

Comment: Right, but if you change them to be not equal, it won't. The point is that you're calling the same next instruction regardless of whether you jump or not. You need to not do that. I guess for the behaviour you want, you need to both move the label and change to `je`.

Comment: No, I needed to add an "IN CASE" label so it jumps there instead. I wanted it to not call it by testing two EQUAL registers and then telling it to JUMP WHEN THEY ARE NOT EQUAL, SO IT JUMPS BECAUSE THEY ARE. I am afraid your solution is mindless and doesn't suggest you understand the scope of my code.

Comment: @MargaretRosa, no you didn't. The solution you chose is probably the worst one. It has two jumps rather than one, which is completely unnecessary. All you need is to `je` and move the label.

Comment: "Equal they are or not. No other options, there are." If you want to show the box if they are not equal, skip the invoke by jumping past it if they are  equal. Not really rocket science.

Comment: It's not my way though; I only wanted it to work my way as explained in all caps above.

Comment: ... but if it worked the way you wanted it to, you wouldn't be here asking for help, right? We're just trying to give you an optimal solution.

Comment: It did work my way; Jose showed that you need an "ELSE IF" label so it has another choice.

Answer (score 3):

I did not program Applesoft Basic in a while ... decades...

This is what your program looks like:

```
10 a = 5
20 b = 5
30 if a <> b then goto 40
40 PRINT "Here I am!"
50 END
```

Here is your prefered fix:

```
10 a = 5
20 b = 5
30 if a <> b then goto 50
40 goto 60
50 PRINT "Here I am!"
60 END
```

And this is the simplified version:

```
10 a = 5
20 b = 5
30 if a = b then goto 50
40 PRINT "Here I am!"
50 END
```

As you can see, the simplified version is one line less and as such, preferable.

Comment: None of those examples are illustrative of my way.